# Dissolving polygons contained within the same larger polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, overlapping-features, dissolve

There is a layer in QGIS that contains multiple polygons, and I want to dissolve the polygons which are inside another polygon.

I don't want to dissolve the entire layer of polygons. For example, in the following map, is there a way in the QGIS to make it two polygons only by combining any inner polygon with the bigger one containing it?

I want to select the polygons automatically. It is very hard to select polygons manually since there are more than 1.2K polygons.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Taras Run Vector -> Geoprocessing Tools -> Dissolve

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To merge all the features of layer *'polygon2'* inside the same same polygon from layer *'polygon1'* automatically (without manual selection), use `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Aggregate` ([see documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#aggregate)) with *'polygon2'* as input layer and this expression as `Group by expression`:

```
array_first(overlay_within('polygon1', $id))
```

2 purple polygons = layer *'polygon1'*; 6 yellow polygons = layer *'polygon2'*; aggregated result consists of two features: *A)* 4 part MultiPolgon with blue outline, *B)* 2 part MultiPolygon with red outline:

[image]

If the polygons are all on the same layer, you can use the following trick:

Buffer the input layer with a (very small) negative buffer of like 0.1 meters. Then set the initial polygon layer as input layer in the Aggregate tool and the buffered layer in the expression:

```
array_first(overlay_within('buffer', $id))
```

Comment: Thank you. But unfortunately, all polygons are on the same layer.

Comment: Then simply replace the layer's name in the expression by your polygon layer's name - in my case: `polygon2` instead of `polygon1` (or use the variable `@layer` to get the current layer). Or even easier: dissolve the whole layer and run `multipart to single parts`.

Comment: Added a solution in case all polygons are on the same layer, see edited answer at the bottom.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to dissolve in-place:

1. Start edit mode for the layer.
2. Select the bounding and interior polygons
3. Click "Merge selected features" button ([image]) in the Advanced digitizing Toolbar.
4. Repeat 2-3 for all bounding and interior polygons separately.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. is there a way to select polygons automatically?

Answer (score 10):

To get as a different layer from the original one, use the following steps.

1. Select the polygons you want to dissolve
2. Run "Vector Geometry" -> "Dissolve tool". (Check "Selected features only")
3. Then run "Vector geometry" -> "Multipart to singleparts" tool for the dissolved layer.